# How to convert rows from multiple tables into columns with values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have one user table.

[image]

and second language table which contains language that user can speak

[image]

and third passport table which contains user's passport details(user can have multiple passport)

[image]

[I have 5 more table except these]

I want to convert these language and passport rows to columns into one result-set(having user details also) and in the result set it should show yes/no value for language and passport column for every user record depending on what language user can speak and what passport they have.Output would be as given below:

[image]

We can do this by using PIVOT.I tried with single table but how to do it for multiple tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

First the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblUser 
            (
                userid INT, 
                userName VARCHAR(100),
                department VARCHAR(100)
            )
CREATE TABLE #tblLanguage 
            (
                uniqueid INT,
                userid INT,
                [language] VARCHAR(100)
            )
CREATE TABLE #tblContryPassport
            (
                uniqueid INT,
                userid INT,
                contryPassport VARCHAR(100)
            )
INSERT INTO #tblUser
VALUES
    (1,'aa','TT'),
    (2,'bb','gg'),
    (3,'cc','rr'),
    (4,'dd','dd')
INSERT INTO #tblLanguage
VALUES
    (1,1,'American'),
    (1,1,'Arabic'),
    (1,2,'Azerbaujani'),
    (1,3,'Bulgarian'),
    (1,3,'Chaochow'),
    (1,4,'Behdini')
INSERT INTO #tblContryPassport
VALUES
    (1,1,'Hongkong'),
    (1,1,'Malaysia'),
    (1,2,'Spain'),
    (1,3,'China'),
    (1,4,'India'),
    (1,4,'UK')
```

Then concat the unique column for the pivot. If there is two then choose one of them:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX),
        @colsWithIsNull VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        #tblContryPassport.contryPassport AS Name
    FROM
        #tblContryPassport
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        #tblLanguage.[language] AS Name
    FROM
        #tblLanguage
), CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) AS iRank,
        CTE.Name
    FROM
        CTE
)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(Name),
                     QUOTENAME(Name)),
        @colsWithIsNull=COALESCE(@colsWithIsNull + ',ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(Name)+',''no'') AS '+QUOTENAME(Name),
                     'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(Name)+',''no'') AS '+QUOTENAME(Name))
FROM
    CTE2
WHERE
    iRank=1
```

Then do a dynamic pivot like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N';WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        #tblContryPassport.userid,
        ''yes'' AS Answer,
        #tblContryPassport.contryPassport AS Name
    FROM
        #tblContryPassport
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        #tblLanguage.userid,
        ''yes'' AS Answer,
        #tblLanguage.[language] AS Name
    FROM
        #tblLanguage
)
SELECT
    userName,
    department,
    '+@colsWithIsNull+'
FROM
(
    SELECT
        #tblUser.userid,
        #tblUser.userName,
        #tblUser.department,
        CTE.Answer,
        CTE.Name
    FROM
        #tblUser
        JOIN CTE
            ON #tblUser.userid=CTE.userid
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Answer)
    FOR Name IN ('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Then in my case I will drop the temp tables:

```
DROP TABLE #tblUser
DROP TABLE #tblContryPassport
DROP TABLE #tblLanguage
```

Comment: @ Arion: I need your help once again.Please see the updated question after the label called " Moving further with other tables "

Comment: Yeah I think that is going to be hard to get that output because as you say that you do not have any relationship. The edit you did is a new question so if you want new answers. Ask a new question.

Comment: I asked new question and remove that from this question.Please keep in mind current scenario as i need to merge that solution to this one while answering the new one.URL of new question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531771/need-t-sql-help-for-converting-rows-from-multiple-tables-into-columns-with-value. thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
select
  *
from
(
  select
    u.Username, u.department, c.countrypassport
  from User U
  inner join country C
    on C.userid=U.userid
) DataTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(countrypassport)
  FOR countrypassport
  IN (
    [American],[Arabic],.....
  )
) PivotTable
```