# Need T-SQL help for converting Rows from multiple tables into Columns with values in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have a table tblUser:

**tblUser**

[image]

and a table tblBCE and data in the given below:

**tblBCE**

[image]

and a master table mstBCE which contains label text to display in front end application. This table contains data for other tab also but currently i want only for tabType 'BCE',I will do for other tab myself once i got the concept.

**mstBCE**

[image]

There is no relation between tblBCE and mstBCE tables,we need to follow the top to bottom sequence only.

In front end application i display these data only by sequence i.e.

i follow the sequence of both table to display data like for label "tab display text111111 BCE" comment value should be comments111111 and for label "tab display text222222 BCE" should be "comments22222" etc.

In front end it display as given below for one user:

[image]

so the output would be.

**Output**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't thin that you will be able to do this without a relation between mstBCE and tblBCE. Because there is no way do know if you are going to output yes or no.

Comment: OK so can we do something like hard code the Option1 to "tab display text111111 BCE" label ,Option2 to "tab display text222222 BCE" etc. as mstBCE only contains label text.

Comment: and for BCE type three column is fixed

Comment: Can you plz show the output you want then? with this changes.

Comment: i have mentioned output in my question.please see the last image in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is improve the schema and do you really need to do this.

To simplify the question it looks like you want to set the column name based on a join to mstBCE. 
You don't need a relation because the number of columns in tblBCE is fixed. Instead use dynamic sql to set the column names selecting from mstBCE pivoted onto one row.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000); 
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT u.[username], u.[department], 
b.[Option1TB] as [' + pvt.[1] + N'], b.[Option1], 
b.[Option2TB] as [' + pvt.[2] + N'], b.[Option2], 
b.[Option3TB] as [' + pvt.[3] + N'], b.[Option3] 
FROM tblBCE as b 
JOIN tblUser as u ON b.[UserID] = u.[userid]; ' 
FROM (
    SELECT [tabconfigid], [tabdata] 
    FROM mstBCE 
    WHERE [tabType] = N'BCE'
) as m 
PIVOT ( MIN(m.[tabdata]) FOR m.[tabconfigid] IN ([1], [2], [3]) ) as pvt; 

EXEC (@sql);
```